# How to troubleshoot problem with setting WebRTC server on vps?

Tags: node.js, webrtc, peer, peerjs

I wrote a simple node express server for webRTC using [peerjs-server](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) and simple client using [peerjs](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/). Everything works fine on localhost, but when I try it on vps, I get error:

```
Firefox can't connect with server ws://my.vps/peerjs/peerjs?key=peerjs&id=hj3hpekwaa38fr00&token=ymtfvhagiw
PeerJS:  Socket closed.
PeerJS:  ERROR Error: Lost connection to server.
Error: "Lost connection to server."
emitError                   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.16/peer.min.js:1:16426
_initializeServerConnection https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.16/peer.min.js:1:12260
emit                        https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.16/peer.min.js:1:25516
onclose                     https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.16/peer.min.js:1:19350
```

Server:

```
const express = require('express');
enter code here`const app = express();
const ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;

app.use(express.static('./public'));

const server = app.listen(80, () => { // 3000 on localhost
    console.log('Express server listen on port ' + 80);
});

const options = { debug: true };
const peerserver = ExpressPeerServer(server, options);

app.use('/peerjs', peerserver);
app.use('/*', express.static('./public/index.html'));
```

Client:

```
var peer = new Peer('', {
    host: location.hostname,
    port: location.port || (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 443 : 80),
    path: '/peerjs',
    debug: 3
});

peer.on('open', function (id) {
    console.log(id);
});
```

Any help appreciate.

Comment: Were you finally able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are connecting with server `ws://my.vps/`, which is a web socket to a server at http://my.vps/ which doesn't seem to exist.

It should probably also be using https (or wss)